# I need vector fonts in PDF

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf

I've processed this file with PDFLaTeX and got a PDF with a raster font. I need vector fonts. What I did wrongly?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
xxx
\end{document}
```

Debian Linux "testing".

Comment: Add `\usepackage{lmodern}` or do a *full* install of TeX Live.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` helped